# Set gif or mp4 avatar via telethon (telegram API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I tried to set animated photo via telethon, but any suggestions not working

my code:

```
client = TelegramClient(None, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.connect()
    await client(functions.photos.UploadProfilePhotoRequest(
        video=await client.upload_file("er2.mp4")

    ))

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Error:
**telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.VideoFileInvalidError: The given video cannot be used (caused by UploadProfilePhotoRequest)**

where er.mp4 - my local file
I'm stucked with this already for 2 days

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you try to use this file directly in telegram - to see if telegram will accept this file? OR maybe it can't find file and you should use `/full/path/to/er2.mp4`

Comment: using Google I found post on telethon github which mentions some limitation for video file [Theleton - Video avatars ("profile photos")](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Video-avatars-%28%22profile-photos%22%29)